# Javascript sorting function causes game to quit

Tags: javascript

I have a game in Javascript. It plays clues with buttons and the user needs to remember which buttons to click after the button is lit up and the clue plays.

I have a variable called pattern that holds an array to represent the different buttons to play in different order. Instead of having this fixed pattern I created a function that sorts the array and then I call it in the `startGame` function, which initiates the game. However, this time with this sorting function, although I click the correct button that is played and lit up, the game automatically quits and says "you lose" which is what happens when you press the incorrect button.

What do I do? I am guessing it has something to do with the guess function but how do I fix it?

```js
//Global Contants
 
const cluePauseTime = 333; //how long to pause in between clues
const nextClueWaitTime = 1000; //how long to wait before starting playback of the clue sequence

//Global variables
var clueHoldTime = 500; //how long to hold each clue's light/sound
var pattern = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5];
var progress = 0;
var gamePlaying = false;
var tonePlaying = false;
var volume = 0.5;
var guessCounter = 0;

function randNum() {
  pattern.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random() )

}
function startGame() {
  
  progress = 0;
  gamePlaying = true;

  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.add("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.remove("hidden");

  playClueSequence();
  
  randNum();
  
}

function stopGame() {
  gamePlaying = false;

  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.add("hidden");
}

function lightButton(btn){
  document.getElementById("button"+btn).classList.add("lit")
}
function clearButton(btn){
  document.getElementById("button"+btn).classList.remove("lit")
}

function playSingleClue(btn){
  if(gamePlaying){
    lightButton(btn);
    playTone(btn,clueHoldTime);
    setTimeout(clearButton,clueHoldTime,btn);
  }
}

function playClueSequence(){
  guessCounter = 0;
  let delay = nextClueWaitTime; //set delay to initial wait time
  for(let i=0;i<=progress;i++){ // for each clue that is revealed so far
    console.log("play single clue: " + pattern[i] + " in " + delay + "ms")
    setTimeout(playSingleClue,delay,pattern[i]) // set a timeout to play that clue
    delay += clueHoldTime;
    delay += cluePauseTime;
  }
}

function loseGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Game Over. You lost.");
}
function winGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Yayyyyy, you win!!");
}

function guess(btn) {
  console.log("user guessed: " + btn);
  if (!gamePlaying) {
    return;
  }
  if (pattern[guessCounter] == btn) {
    if (guessCounter == progress) {
      if (progress == pattern.length - 1) {
        winGame();
      } else {
        progress++;
        playClueSequence();
      }
    } else {
      guessCounter++;
    }
  } else {
    loseGame();
  }
}
// Sound Synthesis Functions
const freqMap = {
  1: 261.6,
  2: 329.6,
  3: 392,
  4: 466.2,
  5: 432.8,
  6: 336.2
};
function playTone(btn, len) {
  o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    stopTone();
  }, len);
}
function startTone(btn) {
  if (!tonePlaying) {
    o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
    g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
    tonePlaying = true;
  }
}
function stopTone() {
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = false;
}

//Page Initialization
// Init Sound Synthesizer
var context = new AudioContext();
var o = context.createOscillator();
var g = context.createGain();
g.connect(context.destination);
g.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
o.connect(g);
o.start(0);
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Hello!</title>

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Shah's Memory Game</h1>

    <p>
      Welcome to the game that will test your memory!
    </p>

    <button id="startBtn" onclick="startGame()">
      Start
    </button>
    <button id="stopBtn" class="hidden" onclick="stopGame()">
      Stop
    </button>

    <div id="gameButtonArea">
      <button
        id="button1"
        onclick="guess(1)"
        onmousedown="startTone(1)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button2"
        onclick="guess(2)"
        onmousedown="startTone(2)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button3"
        onclick="guess(3)"
        onmousedown="startTone(3)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button4"
        onclick="guess(4)"
        onmousedown="startTone(4)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button5"
        onclick="guess(5)"
        onmousedown="startTone(5)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
      <button
        id="button6"
        onclick="guess(6)"
        onmousedown="startTone(6)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      ></button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plz add the HTML.

Comment: This is a lot to debug without being able to run the application. Add the html or specify the problem with a minimal reproducible code

Comment: It is hard to experiment plz share everything important like CSS. You are adding and removing classes, how will we know what they are doing.

Comment: Also can you plz tell me why are you using attributes instead of event listeners.

Comment: I find it very difficult to figure out what you're doing in your program. Can you be specific with the problem you're facing rather than asking us to debug from your whole program?

Comment: I don't see the sorting function having any problem so the title seems misleading

Comment: @RifatBinReza Ye, It is! Also this `pattern[guessCounter] == btn` might be one of the many problems as `btn` will be `1, 2, 3,....` and `pattern[guessCounter]`  will be `0, 1, 2, 3,....`. We need to add or subtract 1.

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal checkout the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment the `guessCounter` every time there's a successful guess. You cannot reset `guessCounter = 0` every time you invoke the `playClueSequence()` function, rather clear it when you `startGame()`. Find the comments in the code for better clarification.

```js
//Global Contants
 
const cluePauseTime = 333; //how long to pause in between clues
const nextClueWaitTime = 1000; //how long to wait before starting playback of the clue sequence

//Global variables
var clueHoldTime = 500; //how long to hold each clue's light/sound
var pattern = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5];
var progress = 0;
var gamePlaying = false;
var tonePlaying = false;
var volume = 0.5;
var guessCounter = 0;

function randNum() {
  pattern.sort(() => Math.random() - Math.random() )

}
function startGame() {
  
  progress = 0;
  // You can reset the guessCounter here every time you start the game
  guessCounter = 0;
  gamePlaying = true;

  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.add("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.remove("hidden");

  playClueSequence();
  
  randNum();
  console.log(pattern.toString())
}

function stopGame() {
  gamePlaying = false;

  document.getElementById("startBtn").classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById("stopBtn").classList.add("hidden");
}

function lightButton(btn){
  document.getElementById("button"+btn).classList.add("lit")
}
function clearButton(btn){
  document.getElementById("button"+btn).classList.remove("lit")
}

function playSingleClue(btn){
  if(gamePlaying){
    lightButton(btn);
    playTone(btn,clueHoldTime);
    setTimeout(clearButton,clueHoldTime,btn);
  }
}

function playClueSequence(){
  // You cannot reset the guessCounter here every time otherwise, the game will not progress
  //guessCounter = 0;
  let delay = nextClueWaitTime; //set delay to initial wait time
  for(let i=0;i<=progress;i++){ // for each clue that is revealed so far
    console.log("play single clue: " + pattern[i] + " in " + delay + "ms")
    setTimeout(playSingleClue,delay,pattern[i]) // set a timeout to play that clue
    delay += clueHoldTime;
    delay += cluePauseTime;
  }
}

function loseGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Game Over. You lost.");
}
function winGame() {
  stopGame();
  alert("Yayyyyy, you win!!");
}

function guess(btn) {
  console.log("user guessed: " + btn);
  if (!gamePlaying) {
    return;
  }
  if (pattern[guessCounter] == btn) {
    if (guessCounter == progress) {
      if (progress == pattern.length - 1) {
        winGame();
      } else {
        progress++;
        playClueSequence();
      }
    } else {
      //guessCounter++;
    }
    // You need to increment the guessCounter every time it's a successful guess to move forward to the next pattern element
    guessCounter++;
  } else {
    loseGame();
  }
}
// Sound Synthesis Functions
const freqMap = {
  1: 261.6,
  2: 329.6,
  3: 392,
  4: 466.2,
  5: 432.8,
  6: 336.2
};
function playTone(btn, len) {
  o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    stopTone();
  }, len);
}
function startTone(btn) {
  if (!tonePlaying) {
    o.frequency.value = freqMap[btn];
    g.gain.setTargetAtTime(volume, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
    tonePlaying = true;
  }
}
function stopTone() {
  g.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, context.currentTime + 0.05, 0.025);
  tonePlaying = false;
}

//Page Initialization
// Init Sound Synthesizer
var context = new AudioContext();
var o = context.createOscillator();
var g = context.createGain();
g.connect(context.destination);
g.gain.setValueAtTime(0, context.currentTime);
o.connect(g);
o.start(0);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>Hello!</title>

    <!-- import the webpage's stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />

    <!-- import the webpage's javascript file -->
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Shah's Memory Game</h1>

    <p>
      Welcome to the game that will test your memory!
    </p>

    <button id="startBtn" onclick="startGame()">
      Start
    </button>
    <button id="stopBtn" class="hidden" onclick="stopGame()">
      Stop
    </button>

    <div id="gameButtonArea">
      <button
        id="button1"
        onclick="guess(1)"
        onmousedown="startTone(1)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      >1</button>
      <button
        id="button2"
        onclick="guess(2)"
        onmousedown="startTone(2)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      >2</button>
      <button
        id="button3"
        onclick="guess(3)"
        onmousedown="startTone(3)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      >3</button>
      <button
        id="button4"
        onclick="guess(4)"
        onmousedown="startTone(4)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      >4</button>
      <button
        id="button5"
        onclick="guess(5)"
        onmousedown="startTone(5)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      >5</button>
      <button
        id="button6"
        onclick="guess(6)"
        onmousedown="startTone(6)"
        onmouseup="stopTone()"
      >6</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```